# SQL query for percentage calculation - single column, all data, using like/wildcard

Tags: sql, percentage

I'm looking for SQL query that will give me a simple percentage value based upon the number of occurrences of a value in a table with a single data column.
Example:
Table has single column of data, which has a header and 10 data rows:

```
COLUMN_HEADER
XYZ://abc123xyz456-0
XYZ://abc123xyz456-1
XYZ://abc123xyz456-2
XYZ://abc123xyz456-3
ABC://abc123xyz456-4
XYZ://abc123xyz456-5
XYZ://abc123xyz456-6
ABC://abc123xyz456-7
XYZ://abc123xyz456-8
XYZ://abc123xyz456-9
```

I'm looking for the query to look for all data *that does not start with* XYZ://*
and give that as a % of the row count.

In the above example, there are two rows that start with ABC:// and eight that start XYZ:// therefore the result should be:
80.00%

(so 8 out of 10 rows do not start with XYZ://)

As you can tell by now I'm a noob in SQL.

MS SQL 2014

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when COLUMN_HEADER like 'XYZ://%' then 1.0 else 0 end) as xyz_ratio
```

Your logic and examples are backwards.  80% of the rows have values that *do* start with "XYZ://".  Use `like` or `not like` as appropriate.